Is RefCell::as_ptr guaranteed to stay the same for a given RefCell?
I am looking for a way to impl Hash for MyStruct where MyStruct contains `Rc<RefCell> (yes, it's a linked list of a sort).
This answer suggests std::ptr::hash(self.next.as_ref()), but I have doubts whether there are any guarantees reg the RefCell address.
In Ruby, I'd use object_id method inplace of as_ptr as a unique identifier to hash. If as_ptr may change during execution, is there any similar identifier for a given RefCell ?
I'm trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/

tried #[Derive(Debug)] - didn't work, as RefCell doesn't impl Hash by default, what makes sense
came across suggestions to RefCell::borrow and avoid panic-s somehow - didn't sound reliable


The problem is the usage RefCell. Linked lists are non-idiomatic in Rust. See also https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/. Do you need to hash the contents or the address?

Linked lists look awkward to me in Rust, good to hear they're not idiomatic.
Hashing the content would only work if I did it recursively, so a hash of a given item would represent the whole list's tail starting from the current item.
Otherwise, 2 nodes with the same value + next item's value would have the same hash, but they could be in different lists altogether.

Thanks for the book!
I guessed that It's easier (and faster) to get RefCell's identifier hashed, hence the question.

If the contents can change (as implied by the RefCell) and/or there might be duplicate contents then usually hashing the ID will be incorrect. The usefulness of hashing the ID is very limited to exotic secanrios.

How you solve this is going to be very dependent on how Leetcode makes their Rust version. I think they'd use Rc<_>, in which case you'd use Rc::as_ptr. There's no reason to bring RefCell into this, but if they did, it would be irrelevant.

There's no Rust version of the problem, and I guess I know why)
I tried to make it without RefCell, but I had to add it back to be able to change each Node twice: on making a list and on updating the random attr.

No, RefCell::as_ptr is not guaranteed to be stable in the general case. An example:
let a = RefCell::new(42);
println!("address: {:?}", a.as_ptr());
let b = Some(a);
println!("address: {:?}", b.unwrap().as_ptr());

Prints something like this:
address: 0x7ffe3737d228
address: 0x7ffe3737d300

The reason is that the RefCell object was moved. See it in action on Playground.

As for an actual solution: Rust doesn't make it easy, but there's a way. In your case, the object is an Rc<RefCell<_>>. The internal pointer of an immutable Rc cannot change since every Rc instance points to the same heap address. Thus, Rc::as_ref() is stable.
I wrote some code that demonstrates using Rcs as HashMap keys by heap address, but it's not pretty: Playground.

good, so I have to "bake" RefCell into something immutable first.

@DeCay Baking it into something immutable is not enough. For example, a Box won't work since you can move the RefCell out it. The Rc is really a special case because you can't move its value out of it due to shared ownership.
